# MongoDB - Meteor - Update Array on nested schemas

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

I am having troubles trying to implement an update on my Schema. I don't know what I am doing wrong. These are the two schemas:

```
const PermissionsSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  canAdmin: {
    type: Boolean,
    defaultValue: false,
  },
  canManageAudience: {
    type: Boolean,
    defaultValue: false,
  },
  canManageUsers: {
    type: Boolean,
    defaultValue: false,
  },
  allowedToPost: {
    type: [String],
    defaultValue: [],
  },
  allowedToChat: {
    type: [String],
    defaultValue: [],
  },
  allowedToAdmin: {
    type: [String],

    });

FBUsers.schema = new SimpleSchema({
  _id: {
    type: String,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    optional: true,
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    optional: true,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
  },
  surname: {
    type: String,
    optional: true,
  },
  birthdate: {
    type: Date,
    optional: false,
  },
  position: {
    type: String,
    optional: true,
  },
  avatar: {
    type: String,
    optional: true,
  },
  avatarUpdatedAt: {
    type: Date,
    optional: true,
  },
  isAdmin: {
    type: Boolean,
  },
  permissions: {
    type: PermissionsSchema,
  },
  calendar: {
    type: String,
    allowedValues: CALENDAR_OPTIONS.map(x => x.key),
    optional: true,
  },
  groups: {
    type: [String],
    defaultValue: [],
  },
  device: {
    type: String,
    allowedValues: DEVICE_PLATFORMS.map(x => x.toLowerCase()),
  },
  label: {
    type: String,
  },
  disableLabel: {
    type: Boolean,
    defaultValue: false,
  },
});
  defaultValue: [],
  },
```

I want to update permissions field (maybe in one query I want to update/push `allowedToPost` array permission, or maybe i want to update/push `allowedToChat` array permission.

My query needs to handle that I can have  and array of userIDs (multiUpdate) and I want to push the permission with an array of groupId (the permission that I am updating will be for that array I am updating).

The final query I made was:

```
          return FBUsers.update({ _id: { $in: userIds}}, { $push: { 'permissions.allowedToPost': { $each: groupIdsArr } } });
```

I am getting:

> Exception while invoking method 'fbuser.setPermissions' MongoError:
>   The field 'permissions.allowedToChat' must be an array but is of type
>   String in document {_id: "I92aX1vfAfc3KSO8vn9cEQ0MwSt1"}

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Seem to be you are passing a string field to allowedToChat but must be an array

Comment: If you show your document `_id: "I92aX1vfAfc3KSO8vn9cEQ0MwSt1"` it's likely that the existing value of `permissions.allowedToChat` is a string instead of an array of strings.

Comment: Also you'll need `{multi: true}` to update more than one document in that update.